# I need to return QHash value from a function, I test this code in Qt where is the error

Tags: qt

```
class DataInputSetting
{
public:
     // constructor
     DataInputSetting();

     QHash<QString,QString> InputData;

     InputData Load(const std::string &file);

     void Save(const InputData &inputData, const std::string &file);
};
```

Comment: You should detail more what is the error you're getting. Does it fail to compile or does it run without doing anything?

It is a good practice in stack overflow to detail what you're trying to do, what you attempted to fix and what is getting you confused :)

Comment: error: C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Load'

Comment: Looks like you're trying to define a type, but you forgot to include the keyword `typedef`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would declare your class in the following way:

```
class DataInputSetting
{
public:
     // constructor
     DataInputSetting();

     QHash<QString, QString> InputData;

     // Function returns a hash.
     QHash<QString, QString> Load(const std::string &file);

     void Save(const InputData &inputData, const std::string &file);
};
```

The problem is that you make your `Load()` function to return a concrete variable (class member). However C++ syntax assumes, that you have to declare the `type` your function returns, and not a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `InputData` as a type, not a variable.

```
class DataInputSetting
{
public:
     // constructor
     DataInputSetting();

     // NOTE: use of typedef makes 'InputData` an alias of 'QHash<QString,QString>'
     typedef QHash<QString,QString> InputData;

     InputData Load(const std::string &file);

     void Save(const InputData &inputData, const std::string &file);
};
```